# EntLib5: Loggin application block not logging to Event Log (exception: type LogWriter cannot be constructed)- Can anyone help?

Tags: .net, logging, enterprise-library, application-blocks, logging-application-block

HI there,

I just setup the logging application block part of Enterprise Library 5. I think i have done it correct but its not logging to the event log it errors on the write method and gives me the following exception.

```
    The type LogWriter cannot be constructed. 
         You must configure the container to supply this value.
```

Can anyone do me a check or tell me what i am missing..

First of all i am running in windows 7 with a winforms application.

Here is my method that creates the log and you see the write method.

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{
    public void SendTest(string test)
    {
        LogEntry log = new LogEntry();
        log.EventId = 300;
        log.Message = test;
        log.Categories.Add("testing");
        log.Severity = TraceEventType.Information;
        log.Priority = 5;
        Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Write(log);

    }
}
```

All my configs were built using the entlib5 editor and not by hand. And confirmed this si the path where entlib.config is

```
    filePath="C:\myapp\entlib.config" />
```

Here is my app.config which POINTS to my entlib.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
</configSections>
<enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource selectedSource="System Configuration Source">
    <sources>
        <add name="System Configuration Source" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.SystemConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="File-based Configuration Source" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.FileConfigurationSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            filePath="C:\myapp\entlib.config" />
    </sources>
    <redirectSections>
        <add sourceName="File-based Configuration Source" name="Redirected Section" />
    </redirectSections>
</enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup></configuration>
```

and here is my entlib.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    </configSections>
    <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
        <listeners>
            <add name="Event Log Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter"
                log="" machineName="." traceOutputOptions="None" />
        </listeners>
        <formatters>
            <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}"
                name="Text Formatter" />
        </formatters>
        <categorySources>
            <add switchValue="All" name="General">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="Event Log Listener" />
                </listeners>
            </add>
        </categorySources>
        <specialSources>
            <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
            <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
            <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="Event Log Listener" />
                </listeners>
            </errors>
        </specialSources>
    </loggingConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT**
The question has been updated with the new  app.config, to include

```
<redirectSections>
    <add sourceName="File-based Configuration Source" name="Redirected Section" />
</redirectSections>
```

I am still getting an error.

> ```
>  Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type
> ```
>
> LogWriter, key ""

and inner exception is

> Resolution of the dependency failed,
>   type =
>   \"Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter\",
>   name = \"(none)\".\r\nException
>   occurred while: while
>   resolving.\r\nException is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The type
>   LogWriter cannot be constructed. You
>   must configure the container to supply
>   this
>   value.\r\n-----------------------------------------------\r\nAt the time of the exception, the
>   container was:\r\n\r\n  Resolving
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter,(none)\r\n"}

I used the EntLib configurator to create both files.

The entlib.config i accepted the default as it appears to have the EventLog listener included..

**EDIT**

this is my line in the entlib.config file, log is empty-- ermm is this correct?

```
    <add name="Event Log Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter"
        log="" machineName="." traceOutputOptions="None" />
```

**EDIT**

MY Logger.write is in a dll but my app.config / entlib.config are in a winforms app.. the winforms app has a reference to the dll project where i write the log.

Both the dll and the winforms has a reference to

```
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging
```

and also using unity, has

```
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity

   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martin, you've created a file-based configuration source, but you haven't redirected the logging section to it.

Add the following to App.config inside enterpriseLibrary.ConfigurationSource node:

```
<redirectSections>
      <add sourceName="File-based Configuration Source" name="loggingConfiguration" />
</redirectSections>
```

In addition, I recommend the Configuration Sources Labs from the [Enterprise Library 5.0 Hands-on Labs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4f8cd377-5522-4f45-a024-44a6ca5111ec) set. It covers this and more advanced scenarios.

Comment: Thanks grigori, yep i had this missing i now have updated it.. i will update my question...  It is erroring still. Any ideas?